# Передача дочернего объекта в функцию

Tags: c++

Имеется просто код:

```
void foo(A a){
  a.speak();
}

class A{
public:
    void speak(){cout << "A speak\n";}
};

class B : public A{
public:
    void speak(){cout << "B speak\n";}
};

int main(){
 A a;
 B b;
 foo(a);
 foo(b);
}
```

Из книг что я прочел я узнал что указатель типа А может ссылаться на объекты дочек класса А, но тут в функцию объект b передается по значению и при этом код работает. Я не могу понять, почему так происходит, разве компилятор не должен ругаться на эту строку?

Comment: Копайте в сторону "object slicing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В комментарии упомянули "object slicing", но это не совсем тот ответ который вам нужен. Грубо говоря при вызове `foo(b);` происходит копирование.

Объект типа B копируется в объект типа A и проиходит "object slicing". В вашем примере нет потерь данных, но в реальных объектах они могут быть. Например:

```
class A {
   int foo;
};

class B : public A {
   int bar;
};
```

Объект типа B имеет два поля. Но если бы вы написали:

```
B b;
A a = b;
```

Информация `b` о `bar` теряется в `a`.

Компилятор на такое не ругается потом что это его "нормальное" поведение. Он без труда может разрешить такую ситуацию просто "не копировав" поля. И ошибок не будет ведь вашей функции не нужны поля класса `B`.

Comment: _"просто затерев параметры"_ 1. Это не параметры. 2. Он не затирает, а копирует же.

Comment: Благодарю вас, все понятно. То есть ошибки нет так как А не имеет поля int bar и происходит что-то типо сужения структуры

Comment: @Qwertiy ой. спасибо. исправляю. Не "затирает", а "не копирует". так точнее.